# класть, ложить, положить—weird perfective and imperfective pairs?

Tags: вид

So, does anyone want to attempt an explanation as to why **класть—положить** are a pair.

I know that textbooks often state that there are pairs that are "just", for no good reason different, e.g., **говорить—сказать/ брать—взять.**

But if you look at the history of the words, than it's not actually true what the authors say. In fact, **сказывать** is the old imperfective of сказать and **взимать** is the old imperfective of взять.

So, my question is: what pair-shift happened that caused класть—положить? I know that ложить exists (at least colloquially), and кладывать seems to exist on wikislovar.

Anyway, help!)))

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I think the *класть-положить* suppletivism is pan-Slavic, and thus older than Russian as a separate language, much like the irregular past tense of *идти*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally these verbs were different (not sure, whether it was in Old Russian, or in proto-Slavic). "*Класть*" meant "to put **inside**" (cf. *Клад*), while "*Ложить*" meant "to lay **on the surface**" (cf. *Ложе*).

But nowadays this difference is completely lost, and we have *класть* as imperfective, and prefixed forms, such as *положить* as perfective. You shouldn't say *покласть* or *ложить* anymore. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Most widely known language mistakes among native speakers are "ложить" and "зво́нит" (instead of "звони́т"). For example

> Тут ударила мне кровь в голову.
>   — Ложи, — говорю, — взад!
>   А она испужалась.

Рассказ Зощенко "Аристократка" (1923).

In this classic text, saying "ложи́" immidiately indicates education level of the speaker. As far as I know, there is no exact reason for word "ложить" become that inacceptable in imperfect form, but it is possible that "Аристократка" publication and popularity is a reason.

The word "накласть" instead of "положить" does not exist "oficially", though it could be used, usually referring to the process of defecation. "Он пришёл торговать, наклал на прилавок вещей" - implies that the stuff does not have any value.

Comment: "перекласть" also exists, at least colloquially.

Comment: Словарь Даля (XIX) and Словарь Ушакова (1940) has this form. Newer academic dictionaries does not. And I have heard "перекласть" only when talking about bricks ("кирпичная кладка").